# List of reserved words a username can't be?

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a list of common usernames to reserve in a new system?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115425/is-there-a-list-of-common-usernames-to-reserve-in-a-new-system)

I'm working on a site where users will have a custom URL e.g.: http://domain.com/username

I want to avoid the situation where a user registers and creates a username that I later need, e.g. if I want a page at domain.com/about and someone's already named themselves 'about'.

Does anyone have a list of generic words that could be added to a blacklist for this?

Comment: "creates a username that I later need"?  How can we know what you'll need later?  A list of "generic words" would be called a "dictionary", wouldn't it?  How can we guess what possible words you might possibly need in some possible future?

Comment: There are a lot of standard words used in websites e.g.: blog, features, about, contact, login, privacy etc.  I've started compiling a list which is growing, just wondering as someone must have done this before.

Comment: Reading the title of this question, I had to think of [little bobby tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some great answers on this StackOverflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316876/is-there-a-list-of-common-usernames-to-reserve-in-a-new-system

Here's the best list I've found:

http://blog.postbit.com/reserved-username-list.html

Answer (score 26):

I would  have your users page as a sub section. Ie http://domain.com/users/username

There is no way we or even you could guess what pages you might want to create in future

Comment: +1 a lot better than predicting future words you'll be using for your site... for that you need a shiny crystal ball

Comment: I would usually do this but in my situation the simplicity of domain.com/username will be an advantage.

Comment: @evilcelery - So change **users** to **u** adding 3 extra characters will not take away an advantage.

Comment: @evilcelery: The magical "blacklist" of 100's of forbidden names, however, might remove this "advantage".

Comment: This is a bit like how Flickr have done it: http://www.flickr.com/photos/username/ but at some point they made it so http://www.flickr.com/username/ will redirect. However, some people have usernames that cannot redirect, such as `photos` and `about`.

Answer (score 6):

What about using a prefix for site pages, like `domain.com/site/about`? And just make sure usernames can't include the `'/'` character.

Comment: Still makes sense to exclude some usernames, at least in some cases. Otherwise someone seeing this URL: `domain.com/site/admin` might think the user/whatever at that URL is an admin somehow, for the whole `domain.com`.

Answer (score -1):

You can always encode any http reserved characters in the username.
You should do this anyway in case someone decides to register the user name `/../../etc/passwd`

Comment: I am going to use that name for my next username on a forum :-)

Comment: @Ramhound, unless your really name is Bobby Tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: -1 as I'm not sure how this would apply to this problem. this still doesn't stop a user from registering 'about', and him wanting to create an 'about' page later.

Comment: @Craige - if you aren't having a /users/ there is nothing you can do about that without a crystal ball. But it is the correct solution to having a list of symbols/words that aren't acceptable form a URL point of view

Comment: @MartinBeckett - Then should this not be a comment on Tom Squires post?